# How to assign start times of observations to blocks of hours in R

Tags: r, time, block

I have this df where I have columns with date&time, date, and time. And of course the observations of CH4 and the calculated Ratio (I have more, but that is unrelevant to this question).

```
'data.frame':   1420847 obs. of  17 variables
$ Start     : Factor w/ 1469 levels "2013-08-31 23:56:09.000",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...  
$ CO2       : int  1510 1950 1190 1170 780 870 730 740 680 700 ...
$ CH4       : int  66 77 62 58 34 51 36 43 32 40 ...
$ Ratio     : num  0.0437 0.0395 0.0521 0.0496 0.0436 ...  
$ Start_time: POSIXlt, format: "2013-11-20 00:10:05" "2013-11-20 00:10:05" "2013-11-20 00:10:05" "2013-11-20 00:10:05" ...  
$ Start_date: Date, format: "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" "2013-09-01" ...
```

Now I wish to split every day in six blocks of 4 hrs and to assign numbers 1 - 6 to each block. The problem, however, is that I only have the date and time at which the measurements started (`Start_date` and `Start_time`, or the combined `Start`), so I think it is necessary to assign each new `Start_time` to a `block`. The length of the observations varies a lot, so there is no option of assigning a number to it. This is what I wish to accomplish:

```
                  Start  Start_time    Start_date   CO2 CH4       Ratio  block
2013-09-01 00:10:05.000    00:10:05    2013-09-01  1510  66  0.04370861      1
2013-09-01 00:10:05.000    00:10:05    2013-09-01  1950  77  0.03948718      1
2013-09-01 05:16:55.000    05:16:55    2013-09-01  1190  62  0.05210084      2
2013-09-01 05:16:55.000    05:16:55    2013-09-01  1170  58  0.04957265      2
2013-09-01 05:16:55.000    05:16:55    2013-09-01   780  34  0.04358974      2
2013-09-01 12:44:33.000    12:44:33    2013-09-01   870  51  0.05862069      4
2013-09-01 12:44:33.000    12:44:33    2013-09-01   730  36  0.04931507      4
2013-09-01 22:14:23.000    22:14:23    2013-09-01   740  43  0.05810811      6
2013-09-01 22:14:23.000    22:14:23    2013-09-01   680  32  0.04705882      6
2013-09-02 08:37:05.000    08:37:05    2013-09-02   700  40  0.05714286      3
2013-09-02 08:37:05.000    08:37:05    2013-09-02   610  35  0.05737705      3
2013-09-02 17:22:33.000    17:22:33    2013-09-02   630  25  0.03968254      5
2013-09-02 17:22:33.000    17:22:33    2013-09-02   670  40  0.05970149      5
2013-09-02 23:59:44.000    23:59:44    2013-09-02   640  37  0.05781250      6
2013-09-02 23:59:44.000    23:59:44    2013-09-02   730  35  0.04794521      6
```

I have searched this website and also tried Google but, so far, I have found no answer. I have tried the following code, which I found in an answer on this website but no luck.

```
qaa <- split(df, cut(strptime(paste(df$Start_date, df$Start_time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"4 hours"))
```

Previously, I tried to split the number of observations in minutes, so I tried to adjust that code. And to be very honest, I have no idea what I am doing (as you can probably tell).

```
lst<- split(df, df$Start_date)
nobs <- "4 hours" 
List <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) {
  x$grp <- rep(1:(nrow(x)/nobs+1), each = nobs)[1:nrow(x)] 
  split(x, x$grp)}), recursive = FALSE)
b <- as.matrix(do.call("rbind", List))
```

Just to let you know, again, I am a NOOB concerning R so it takes me a lot of time to figure everything out. I understand very little of the language but I am trying my very best to make it work. I really enjoy working with it! If there is already another question like this on this website, please let me know so I can remove this.. I have not found it, though.

Thank you for taking your time to read my question and to consider to answer it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can extract the start hour from the start time (try here: [Dealing with timestamps in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962278/dealing-with-timestamps-in-r)), you could then use the following to assign the correct block number :

```
df$block[df$start_hour>=0 & df$start_hour<4]<-1
df$block[df$start_hour>=4 & df$start_hour<8]<-2
df$block[df$start_hour>=8 & df$start_hour<12]<-3
df$block[df$start_hour>=12 & df$start_hour<16]<-4
df$block[df$start_hour>=16 & df$start_hour<20]<-5
df$block[df$start_hour>=20 & df$start_hour<24]<-6
```

Comment: Yesss! That did it! I am sorry for my late response. At first, I could not see how the page you gave me was applicable to my df.. But I figured it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you install `lubridate` in particular you will be helped as it has useful functions like hour.  cut2 from Hmisc allows you specify some easy brackets for your hours to be split by.

```
library("lubridate")
library("Hmisc")
example<-as.factor('2013-09-01 00:10:05.000')
example<-data.frame(example,timeslot=cut2(hour(as.POSIXct(example,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")),cuts=seq(0,24,4)))
```