# Convert timestamp to milliseconds

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Hey I'm working on SparkR and I have this dataset with data field as this

> 2013-11-01 00:00

Result from str

```
Time    : chr  "2013-11-01 00:00" "2013-11-01 00:10" "2013-11-01 00:20" "2013-11-01 00:30" ...
```

Now I need to convert this data to milliseconds.
Note: I need the Hour and minute.

When I tried a simple `as.numeric` it gives me NA.
How can I do?

Ps:I searched similar questions and when I tried some solutions hour and minute disappear also when I user `format` attribute.

I Did this now I need the inverse procedure from "2013-11-01 09:10" to ->1383293400000

```
a<-TrentoTo$TimeInterval[1]  #1383293400000
b<-as.POSIXct((a)/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
b<-strftime(b, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") #"2013-11-01 09:10"
```

Comment: What is you desired output?

Comment: `as.integer(as.POSIXct(Time))*1000`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to convert to `POSIXct` as in this thread: [Dealing with timestamps in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962278/dealing-with-timestamps-in-r). So the code should be:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Time))
```

Solution using your own example

```
a <- 1383293400000
b <- as.POSIXct((a)/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
b <- strftime(b, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") #"2013-11-01 09:10"
```

outputs

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(b))*1000 == a
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes I needed this and it works. How can I add more digits? 
I got this from your code: 1383260400 
Need: 1383293400000

Comment: @DanieleS check my edit, if it is not working it means that you have some bug in your code in other place and your example does not reproduce the bug.

Comment: I badly explained myself. I need to join them later does this notation will create some trouble?
1.383293e+12 join 1383293400000

Comment: @DanieleS scientific notation is just a way of displaying numbers, it does not affect anything anyhow...

Comment: Thanks for your time.