# Use Hourly data in ts and window function

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have hourly data like the sample below that I am trying to create a time-series from and use the window function with.  My end goal is to use this to train an Arima model.  I'm having a hard time getting `ts()` or `window()` to work with my date time format.  I've also tried using `msts()` but couldn't get it to work with the date time format.  I have gotten `xts()` to work, but it doesn't seem to work correctly with the `window()` or `Arima()`.

Is it possible to use this date time format with `ts()` and the `window()` function?  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
tsData <- ts(SampleData$MedTime[1:24],start='2015-01-01 00:00', frequency=168)

train <- window(tsData,end='2015-01-01 15:00')
```

**Edit Note** The data for this problem has been truncated to only 24 observations from the initial 525 provided. As a result, the `window()` call has been modified as well to a time within the truncated range.

Data:

```
dput(SampleData[1:24,c("DateTime","MedTime")])
```

> SampleData = structure(list(DateTime = c("2015-01-01 00:00", "2015-01-01 01:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 02:00", "2015-01-01 03:00", "2015-01-01 04:00", "2015-01-01 05:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 06:00", "2015-01-01 07:00", "2015-01-01 08:00", "2015-01-01 09:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 10:00", "2015-01-01 11:00", "2015-01-01 12:00", "2015-01-01 13:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 14:00", "2015-01-01 15:00", "2015-01-01 16:00", "2015-01-01 17:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 18:00", "2015-01-01 19:00", "2015-01-01 20:00", "2015-01-01 21:00", 
>                               "2015-01-01 22:00", "2015-01-01 23:00"), MedTime = c(11, 14, 
>                                                                                    17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 7, 6, 7, 
>                                                                                    7, 5, 6, 9, 9)), .Names = c("DateTime", "MedTime"), row.names = c(NA, 
>                                                                                                                                                      24L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I don't think we need 525 example cases. Can you downsize it a bit please?

Answer (score 3):

## Time Series in R

The `ts()` object has a few limitations. Most notably, it doesn't accept time stamps per observation. Instead, it requests a `start` and `freq` (the `end` is optional). Furthermore, the `freq` capabilities are limited to viewing data in terms of seasons.

```
Type      Frequency 
Annual     1
Quarterly  4
Monthly   12
Weekly    52
```

Thus, to generate the correct "season" we would have to calculate a *daily seasonality* where `freq=1440` (=24*60). It gets a bit more complicated after that.

As a result, I would highly suggest creating the time series with an `xts` or `zoo` object.

## Creating a datetime stamp

Next up, one of the reasons for your windowing issues is the date you are supplying is a **string** and not a **POSIXct** or **POSIXlt** object. The prior of which is preferred.

A full breakdown can be found:

[Difference between as.POSIXct/as.POSIXlt and strptime for converting character vectors to POSIXct/POSIXlt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699511/difference-between-as-posixct-as-posixlt-and-strptime-for-converting-character-v)

[Dealing with timestamps in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962278/dealing-with-timestamps-in-r)

With that being said, one of the first steps is to convert your data from **character** form to **POSIXct**

```
# Convert to POSXICT
SampleData$DateTime = as.POSIXct(strptime(SampleData$DateTime, format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

## Windowing

From there, the windowing issue becomes trivial if we create a `xts()` object.

```
# install.packages("xts")
require(xts)

# Create an XTS object to hold the time series
sdts = xts(SampleData$MedTime, order.by = SampleData$DateTime)

# Subset training
train = window(sdts,end= as.POSIXct('2015-01-21 23:00', format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Comment: why did you say that 24*60 is the daily frequency? If the monthly, weekly frequencies are 12 and 52 respectively, shouldn't the daily frequency be 365?

Comment: 24*60 is the daily minute frequency. 24*2 is the half-hour frequency.  24*3600 is the daily second frequency and so on. The 365 in this case would be the daily yearly seasonality. The correct seasonality should indeed be 24 and if data exists for a year, then 8766 (365.25 * 24).